# d3.js color ordinal scale using wildcards?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know that the d3.scale.ordinal function requires an exact x to x mapping i.e.

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["apple", "durian", "lemon"])
    .range(["red","green","yellow"]);
```

My problem is I need to provide colors for fruits that I don't know yet (its in a db that I'll read, but it changes often) e.g.
"chiku", "lychee" etc. (etc. fruits that are not known beforehand).

I'd like to assign these fruits that are not defined in var color,  as "brown".

Questions:
1. can the above be done?
2. can regexp be used in the domain? e.g. lemon.* (for capturing lemonX, lemonY etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to create an `Object` that maps fruits to colors, e.g.

```
var fruit2color = {apple: "red", durian: "green", lemon: "yellow"}
```

Then, given a list of `fruits`, you can then create the range of colors using a `map`. The `map` iterates over each fruit in the array and returns an array containing a color for each fruit. The color is either the one you've put in `fruit2color`, or if the fruit doesn't have an assigned color, is just `'brown'`.

```
var fruits = ["lychee", "chiku", "durian", "plantain", "guava", "apple"];
var colors = fruits.map(function(f){
      return f in fruit2color ? fruit2color[f] : "brown"
    });
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["apple", "durian", "lemon"])
    .range(colors);
```

This code would give you a color range of

```
colors = [ 'brown', 'brown', 'green', 'brown', 'brown', 'red' ]
```

As for the second part of your question, you could use a function `fruit2color` (instead of the object) with a regular expression in order to assign colors, e.g.

```
var patt = /lemon./;
function fruit2color(f){
    if (patt.test(f)) return "yellow";
    else if (f == "apple") return "red";
    else if (f == "durian") return "green";
    else return "brown";
}
var colors = fruits.map(fruit2color);
```

and then pass the resulting colors `array` to `range()`.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, create the `range()` and `domain()` arrays dynamically. I'd support that.